# captcha of click on page in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, click

I have this html code:

```
<input id="luk" type="button" class="play-bt" value="Click Here To Generate Link">
```

After clicking, I get this:

```
<iframe src="LINK_WEB" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true">
```

I want to get "LINK_WEB" In one variable. How I do this in python? (if possible without selenium)

I have this code in python, only for click in the button (with selenium):

```
try:
    boton = driver.find_element_by_id("luk")
    boton.click()
except:
    print "Element is not present"
```

But I do not know what to do next, and use selenium is not a good way for my purpose, help me!!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to achieve this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''<iframe src="LINK_WEB" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true">'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

iframe_tags = soup.find_all('iframe')

for iframe in iframe_tags:
    print(iframe.src)
```

**Ps.:** If you're using `Selenium` to navigate through the website, you can get the page source by typing `driver.page_source`. This way you can change the `s` variable to:

```
s = driver.page_source
```

If you're not using `Selenium`, you can use the `requests` library to get the page source.

Comment: but, s only appears when I click in "<input id="luk" type="button" class="play-bt" value="Click Here To Generate Link">",  How do I click this? the url before the click is the same that after.
Then the process is, download(url) click on  "<input...> capture new html with "<iframe..." and make your code

Comment: Try using the `find_element_by_xpath` method, using the following pattern: `'//input[/@value="Click Here To Generate Link"]'`. This way you'll 
 hopefully find the element and can `.click()` it to get the `driver.page_source`..

Comment: using beautifulsoup can i do that?

Comment: you can't interact with the page using `bs4`... you can achieve this by using a combo of `selenium + bs4`

Comment: Is it required to use selenium? (Is there another library?)

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44214757/3846228)... Andersson said that you can load the page using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) + [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) instead of selenium. But since I don't have the website link, I can't guarantee.