# Python Selenium Page Source

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to get all the IP proxy address from:
https://free-proxy-list.net/

I decided that it will be faster if I get it from source code.

But problem is that I see everything when I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, but when I'm using "page_source" I see only few ip instead of all.

Thanks for help. For DebanjanB I show code. I didn't have to use selenium.

There is code:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
r = requests.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/")
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
ip_list = html.xpath("//tr/td[1]/text()")
port_list = html.xpath("//tr/td[2]/text()")
with open("E:\proxy_lista.csv",'w',newline='') as csvfile:
spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|',                         quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for i in range(0,len(ip_list)):
spamwriter.writerow(ip_list[i].split())
csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because only 20 table rows currently displayed on page.

If you need just to scrape those `IP` numbers, you might need to use [`python-requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) + [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) instead of `selenium`:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

r = requests.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/")
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
ip_list = html.xpath("//tr/td[1]/text()")
```

If it's mandatory for you to use `selenium` you should create an empty list, `append()` required values and `click()` "Next" button. Do this in a `while` loop until "Next" button is enabled